# Spring/React: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported

Tags: reactjs, spring, axios

I'm trying to send a request like so (example in postman):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZLpx.png

Using react(axios), here is my code I have for now:

```js
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        leaderId: user.playerCode,
        logoUrl: null,
        logo: null

    })

    const generateTeam = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        const formObj = new FormData()
        formObj.append('logo', formData.logo)
        formObj.append('body', JSON.stringify({
            name: formData.name,
            leaderId: formData.leaderId,
            logoUrl: formData.logoUrl,
        }))

        try {
            await axios.post(`https://api.ssot.gg/teams`, formObj, {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log(response.data)
                }
            })
        }
        catch (error) {
            alert(`There was a problem with the service.\nIt was unable to process your request.`)
            console.error(`An error occurred while saving user data to local storage.\n ERROR: ${error}`)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="container">
                <h2>MAKE A TEAM</h2>
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={generateTeam}>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <label for="team_name">TEAM NAME: </label>
                                <input name="name" id="team_name" type="text" value={formData.name} onChange={handleTeamNameChange} required/>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="team_logo_file">Team Logo (Max 8MB): </label>
                                <input name="logo" id="team_logo_file" type="file" accept=".jpg, .png" onChange={handleTeamLogoChange} />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
```

I am facing the error: "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported" every time I try sending a request.

Here is the controller for this:

```java
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<TeamDetailsResponse> create(
            @RequestPart(name = "body") UpsertTeamRequest dto,
            @RequestPart(name = "logo") MultipartFile logo
    ) {
        TeamDetailsResponse response = teamService.create(dto, logo);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).